# Execute multiple tests in the same context managers

Tags: python, nose, contextmanager

I have a test setup like this:

```
def test1():
    with Manager1() as m1, m1.get_m2() as m2:
        do_test1(m1, m2)

def test2():
    with Manager1() as m1, m1.get_m2() as m2:
        do_test2(m1, m2)
```

which I run with `nosetests`. Now it turns out that the context managers' `__enter__()` and `__exit__()` methods are expensive, so I would like to change to a setup like:

```
def test():
    with Manager1() as m1, m1.get_m2() as m2:
        do_test1(m1, m2)
        do_test2(m1, m2)
```

but I would like nose to still report separately for each test. I looked into module level and class level `setup()` and `teardown()` methods, but they don't seem to provide the same guarantees for cleanup in the case of exceptions. Is there a clean way to get `nose` to collaborate with context managers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are worried about an exception being raised in the `setup` causing the `teardown` method not to be called then you could use the [`ExitStack`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.ExitStack) class in [`contextlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html). The `ExitStack` can make sure Your manager classes are closed properly if the case of an exception in `setup`.

```
from io import StringIO
from contextlib import ExitStack

managers = []
close_managers = None

def setup():
    global close_managers
    with ExitStack() as exit_stack:
        managers[:] = [exit_stack.enter_context(StringIO()) for _ in range(2)]
        # any exception raised before this line will will cause all the __exit__
        # methods of the given context managers to be called. So this should
        # be the last part of setup
        close_managers = exit_stack.pop_all().close

def teardown():
    m1, m2 = managers
    assert m1.getvalue() == 'test1 m1\ntest2 m1\n'
    assert m2.getvalue() == 'test1 m2\ntest2 m2\n'
    close_managers()

def test1():
    m1, m2 = managers
    m1.write('test1 m1\n')
    m2.write('test1 m2\n')    

def test2():
    m1, m2 = managers
    m1.write('test2 m1\n')
    m2.write('test2 m2\n')
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be the exact use case for `ExitStack` (which is in the contextlib2 package for python2). Works nicely to ensure that `m1.__exit__()` is still called if `m1.get_m2()` raises an exception, while preserving all the functionality of `nosetests`.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at nose [test generation](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/writing_tests.html#test-generators). It might work if you change the code to use yield, something like:

```
from nose.tools import nottest

@nottest
def do_test1(m1, m2):
    m1.write('do_test1 f1')
    m2.write('do_test1 f2')

@nottest
def do_test2(m1, m2):
    m1.write('do_test2 f1')
    m2.write('do_test2 f2')


def test():
    with open('f1.txt', 'wb') as m1, open('f2.txt', 'wb') as m2:
        yield do_test1, m1, m2
        yield do_test2, m1, m2
```

Running tests gets you:

```
$ nosetests context.py -v
context.test(<open file 'f1.txt', mode 'wb' at 0x06A5BF40>, <open file 'f2.txt', mode 'wb' at 0x06A5BF98>) ... ok
context.test(<open file 'f1.txt', mode 'wb' at 0x06A5BF40>, <open file 'f2.txt', mode 'wb' at 0x06A5BF98>) ... ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.004s

OK
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a good idea but I suppose I will lose the capability to selectively run a single test like: `nosetests tests.py:test1`, which I would also like to keep. Or do you have an idea how to preserve that as well?

Comment: Also, have a look at  http://nedbatchelder.com//blog/201508/using_context_managers_in_test_setup.html

Comment: Thanks for the link, but the show-stopper comes at the end: "One caveat about this technique: a context manager's `__exit__` method can be called with information about an exception in progress. The mechanism shown here will never do that." It seems `ExitStack` is just the way to use context managers _with_ correct exception handling if some library like `nose` prevents us from using a `with` block.